# Code for automatic marked headings

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get headings "underproject" to be darker marked automatic? I can do it myself, but want it to happen automatic for all headings.

[Before & After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6xVJ.jpg)

```
Range("A6:L6,A7:D7").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional formatting.  Select the whole table column A to column G and add a new conditional formmating rule and choose the bottom option to enter a formula. enter =left($A1,4)="Unde" click the format button and choose the format you want.

Select the Columns A to C and create another conditional formatting rule and select formula. Enter =left($A1,4)="Navn" and set the format that you want.

this won't merge the cells but in my opinion it is better no keep the cells unmerged as it allows you to sort and filter the data if required.

It is possible using a Macro but you would have to loop through all the cells in column A looking for "Navn" and "Underproject" and use if statements to set the formats.

**Code to delete rows based on heading**

I can't tell from your comment what it is exactly that you want to delete but to can change the critera to suit your requirements.

IMPORTANT: make sure that you make a backup copy of your data before running this macro as changes made by the macro cannot be undone.

```
Sub DeleteEx()

Dim intRow As Integer
Dim strContinue As String
Dim bolDelete As Boolean 'true or false

intRow = 2
strContinue = Cells(intRow, 1) ' the value in A2
bolDelete = False

Do While strContinue <> "" ' this loop will continue down each row as long as there is a value in column A

    If Left(strContinue, 5) = "Under" Or Left(strContinue, 5) = "Navn:" Then 'change this to match your criteria
        'delete the current row
        Rows(intRow & ":" & intRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        intRow = intRow - 1 ' because we deleted a row
    End If

    intRow = intRow + 1
    strContinue = Cells(intRow, 1)
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you... it worked,, I wrote a code, ran it and voila, worked perfect. :)

Comment: another one: what if i want to delete all rows that have this formula: =left($A1,4)="Unde"

Comment: is there a way (code) to search for all rows who begin with ex. "unde" or simular. and delete this one and next , next and so? until all row is deleted.?

Comment: You can't delete a row using conditional formatting or a formula so you would have to write a VBA macro.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some code to delete rows.  The code will delete rows that match a criteria and also delete the rows that come under that heading.  If you only want to delete the heading and keep the other rows then I can easily change the code.

Comment: First, I'm sorry, I did not write this the right way. Second, thank you anyway for the answer. But I'll try once more :)
What I want is a code that removes all the rows with the word, or words that starts with, for example "unde" or "name", and still keeps the other rows between in its place.

Comment: That's ok.  I've updated the answer.  It's an easier bit of code to follow, it simply goes down your list and deletes the row if the word in column A matches the given criteria.  you can use the same code to set formatting too as an alternative to the conditional formatting method.